# Change Emacs prompt

Tags: shell, prompt

[image]

I have Emacs running as a package in MobaXterm
The problem is that Emacs has very ugly prompt.
If I disable PS1 in `.bashrc` than it works in Emacs fine but change MobaXterm terminal as well. Hence I want to change the prompt *only* in Emacs.

How should I change my init file to set up or disable the prompt in Emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks
I figured out that I installed different versions of Emacs packages into MobaXterm.
A few of it has the issues with prompt while others don’t have it
Hence I was able to create a shortcut to “good” one and I  am all set now
Thanks for trying to help